# How to add the array to useState correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I define a state like this:

const [user, setUser] = useState(
[] as { userId: string; userHabbitList: string[] }[],
)

My API will be like this:

```
userList = [
 {
   "id": "1",
   "userHabbit": [
    {
      "userHabbitId": "1"
    },
    {
      "userHabbitId": "2"
    }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "userHabbit": [
    {
      "userHabbitId": "3"
    },
    {
      "userHabbitId": "4"
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

Here is my working:

```
setUser(
 userList.map( e => 
  ({
    userId: e.id, 
    userHabbitList: e.userHabbit.map( u => u.userHabbitId)
  })
 )
)
```

However the userHabbitList still empty,

Here is my expect result:

```
[
 {userId: "1", userHabbitList: ["1","2"]},
 {userId: "2", userHabbitList: ["3","4"]}
]
```

Comment: How (and perhaps more importantly *when*) do you determine that the array is still empty? Also are you receiving an *array* or an *object*? Your example is unclear.

Comment: when I console.log it

Comment: But relative to calling setUser, when exactly does that happen? On the next line, for example, it *definitely* won't have changed yet. Give a [mre].